# Javascript | Node.js - How can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I could really need a hand with this:

```
var getPort = function (callback) {
  serialport.list(function (err, ports) {
    ports.forEach(function (port) {
      if (port.manufacturer === "Prolific Technology Inc. ") {
        callback(port.comName);
      }
    });
  });
};

//How can I set port to comName????
var serialPort = new SerialPort(port, {
  baudrate: 9600
})
```

Please explain how to set the port attribute to the comName that getPort will find.
Of course I could do it like this:

```
var getPort = function (callback) {
      serialport.list(function (err, ports) {
        ports.forEach(function (port) {
          if (port.manufacturer === "Prolific Technology Inc. ") {
            callback(port.comName);
          }
        });
      });
    };

getPort(function(port){
  var serialPort = new SerialPort(port, {
   baudrate: 9600
   });
   //the rest of my program :(
 })
```

But then I'd have to put everything that uses serialPort in getPort's body. Which is really ugly. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing nothing. That's how it works. Putting your code (program) in that callback emphasises that it's executed asynchronously, for every port that was found with that name.

Comment: What exactly do you find so ugly about this? What exactly is "the rest of your program"?

Comment: You don't have to put all the code in there. You can put it anywhere you want but surround it with function and call that function from within the callback. This is just one of possible ways.

Comment: This module of mine, that uses the serialport lib among others, is 400 lines long. So that's why I don't like this. Let's say that there where more async data needed before running my code, would I have to put this entire thing in yet another function??? It would work but it's really ugly. There got to be another way.